How Do You Allow Direct Access to a Subpage in a .Net Core
I have a .Net Core 6 app. It uses OAUTH for authentication. The startup page sets a number of Claims, based on the user, that allow access to the various subpages. If the user starts off on the Home page, access works correctly. If the user tries to go directly to a subpage, access fails. Authentication is working because I log the start and completion of user validation. The setting of the Claims happens during this phase, so I assume that is happening correctly as well.
To better explain, we want the user to be able to go directly to a subpage via a link in an email.
https://abcd.com/Issue/Edit/24-037-M
If the user goes to https://abcd.com/Home first they can then go directly to https://abcd.com/Issue/Edit/24-037-M, however if they try to go directly to https://abcd.com/Issue/Edit/24-037-M the app fails.
This is the error I am getting:

2024-04-23 03:59:21,150 ERROR Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.? [?] - MESSAGE: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Shared__DisplayFiles.ExecuteAsync() in D:\Our_Working_Folder\ABCD\ABCD\Views\Shared_DisplayFiles.cshtml:line 0
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialCoreAsync(String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TextWriter writer)
at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_ABCD_ISSUE_Edit.b__81_1() in D:\Our_Working_Folder\ABCD\ABCD\Views\ABCD_ISSUE\Edit.cshtml:line 612
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(Boolean useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32 count)
at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_ABCD_ISSUE_Edit.ExecuteAsync() in D:\Our_Working_Folder\ABCD\ABCD\Views\ABCD_ISSUE\Edit.cshtml:line 129
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable1 statusCode) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable1 statusCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|22_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

I'm not sure if the startup is not handling the redirect to the subpage properly, or if there is something I am missing.
What do I need to do to allow the proper redirect?

"System.NullReferenceException: Object..." Your view is attempting to access a property of something that is null. You will have to debug the view to figure out what it is.

Open the Exception Settings window in visual studio and put a tick next to "Common Language Runtime" to have VS break as soon as any exception is thrown, then look what is null and why. Note that when an app is starting up a lot of exceptions may be naturally thrown such as socket disposal, operation cancellation etc; start your app without the tick next to, then when your app is running and everything is stable turn the tick on, then make a request to your app's endpoint

@phuzi - Thanks, I should have looked closer at the page. I saw "...at line 0" and figured it wouldn't help. When I looked at the page I saw what i was missing. Thanks!

@phuzi sent me down the correct path. I realized that the home page sets a session variable. Since I was bypassing the Home page, that session variable wasn't being set and was a NULL object. I preset the variable in the Startup and all works as it should.
